# cordova android target not installed and build failed

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, build

My English is not good ，forgive me.I encounter a question for **cordova**.

[image]

this is my cordova requirements ,show that:
android target not installed but I has installed.
if I use cordova-android@5,has not this error 
noe I use cordova-android@6 has this question

[image]
this is my android sdk
I don't know why

Comment: have you installed the updated `command line android tools` from the [site](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), this might be the issue. After downloading this replace it with the tools folder in your Android sdk folder in `C:\Users\<your pc name\AppData\local\android\sdk>`